# On verb/subject agreement in an inverted sentence

Tags: verb-agreement, measure-phrases

I would like to know general grammatical rules on verb-subject agreement in inverted sentences like the following one:

> At stake is much more than just the fortunes of the president.

Although *much more* can be considered singular, *the fortunes of the president* is plural.

On balance, the subject *much more than just the fortunes of the president* does not seem to agree with the singular verb *is*, does it? Or, is the subject *much more than just the fortunes of the president* singular?

Anyway, I guess the proximity of *much more* to the verb has made it the singular *is*.

Could you please tell me the grammatical rationale behind the sentence as well as general rules of thumb in similar ones?

Comment: Please state where you found the example. Such phrases as "The Xs of the Y" can be seen as singular (the whole concept - but it is then better placed in quotes) or plural (the number of Xs). Personally, I would say "are".

Comment: It's taken for granted here that the subject follows the verb in such sentences, PP - V -S structure. This (subject-complement inversion) is covered at [Inversion with a prepositional phrase](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/391250/inversion-with-a-prepositional-phrase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution is that the subject is singular. But the plural agreement is acceptable too, in this case.

**Similar examples with the verb in the singular**

> *At stake **is** more than just **boundaries** or GNP.*
> <sup>From the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* [(COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)</sup>
>
> *At stake **is** more than the **careers** of the two men concerned.*
> <sup>From [Canada's House of Commons debates](https://www.google.com/books/edition/House_of_Commons_Debates_Official_Report/yuFXAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22at+stake+is+more+than%22&dq=%22at+stake+is+more+than%22&printsec=frontcover)</sup>

**Similar examples with the verb in the plural**

> *At stake **are** more than half the **delegates** needed to win the Democratic nomination.*
> <sup>From the *Corpus of Contemporary American English* [(COCA)](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)</sup>
>
> *At stake **are** more than just **economies.***
> <sup>From [U.S. Congressional Record](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Congressional_Record/BlIHJswEJxcC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22at%20stake%20are%20more%20than%20just%22&pg=PA12360&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22at%20stake%20are%20more%20than%20just%22)</sup>

Let's shorten your sentence first a bit, while retaining all the main properties. So, let's consider

[1] *At stake **is** much more than **jobs**.*

Let's put this sentence in the canonical, subject-first form:

[2] *Much more than **jobs** **is** at stake.*

To my ear, at least, changing the verb to plural produces a sentence which is not acceptable English:

[3] <sup>*</sup>*Much more than **jobs** **are** at stake.*

I would be curious to know if others disagree with this. There is reason to think some might, for I found these examples:

> *Yet much more than **words are** needed.*
> <sup>From 'Hearings Before the Committee on Foreign Relations, United States Senate', 1965 [(source)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/To_Amend_the_Arms_Control_and_Disarmamen/cAXrLvgKO_sC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Much%20more%20than%20words%20are%22&pg=PA10&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22Much%20more%20than%20words%20are%22)</sup>
>
> *So much more than **words are** lost in the translation.*
> <sup>From *Sierra Club Bulletin*, Volume 62, 1977 [(source)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22So+much+more+than+words+are+lost+in+the+translation%22)</sup>

At any rate, it seems that when the subject is postposed, the plural verb becomes acceptable:

[4] *At stake **are** much more than **jobs**.*

**Discussion**

There are various circumstances in English where the assignment of singular or plural is in some way non-standard; we refer to these as **overrides**. These are sometimes optional and sometimes obligatory.

Obligatory overrides happen for example with **number-transparent non-count quantificational nouns.** A typical example is illustrated in

[5]  i  *[A lot of work] **was** done.*
      ii  *[A lot of errors] **were** made.*

In [5], the number agreement is determined by the **oblique,** the noun phrase (NP) that is the complement of *of*. Here are some other nouns that can function similarly to *lot* in this respect: *plenty, lots, bags, heaps, loads, oodles, stacks, remainder, rest,  number,* and *couple* ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468),  pp. 349-350).

Here is another example with an obligatory singular override, this time with a formally plural **measure phrase** :

***Twenty dollars seems/<sup>*</sup>seem** a ridiculous amount to pay to go to the movies.*

But the override is optional in

*That ten days we spent in Florida **was/were** fantastic.*

Another example of an optional *singular* override is

[6]  *[One in a hundred students] takes/take drugs.*

Here the head of the subject is the plural noun *students*, and simple agreement would dictate a plural verb. But [6] happens to be synonymous with either of

[7]  i  *[One student in a hundred ] takes/<sup>*</sup>take drugs.*
       ii  *In a hundred students, [ only one] takes/<sup>*</sup>take drugs.*

in which, by simple agreement, the verb must be singular. This, plus the presence of *one*, is presumably why the singular override is possible in [6] (CGEL, p. 504).

And here is an example of an optional plural override:

[8] *The committee has/have not yet come to a decision.*

The noun *committee* is singular, and so simple number agreement would dictate a singular verb. CGEL explains it as follows (p. 502):

> The optionality of the override with collectives reflects the fact that there is potentially a difference of meaning between the versions with singular and plural verbs. From one perspective a committee is a single entity, but since a committee (normally) consists of a plurality of members it can be conceptualised as denoting this plural set. The construction with a plural verb focuses on the members of the committee rather than on the committee as a unit. The plural override is therefore not permitted with predicates that are applicable to the whole but not to the individual members; it is, moreover, of questionable acceptability if the collective has *one* (or *a/another*) as determiner:
>
> [10]  i  *The committee consists/<sup>*</sup>consist of two academic staff and three students.*
>          ii  *This committee, at least, is/<sup>*</sup>are not chaired by one of the premier's cronies.*
>         iii  *One committee, appointed last year, has/<sup>?</sup>have not yet met.*

Note that these doesn't exhaust the list of constructions that feature overrides; see CGEL for more (pp. 501-507). Having said that, interestingly, neither CGEL nor [ComGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0582517346) record the optional override with *more than* constructions like in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Inversion doesn’t make any difference to agreement in that sentence for me.

The word “more” can be singular or plural depending on the meaning, with no difference in form. “At stake is much more than just the fortunes of the president“ = “Much more than just the fortunes of the president is at stake.”

Comment: To my ear, [A] * *Much more than jobs **are** at stake* is not acceptable (I would want to put ***is***). But, to my surprise, I find [B] *At stake **are** much more than jobs* to be acceptable. Here I am really not sure if others would agree. I am very curious: do you find both of these acceptable, or just one of them, or neither?